# What does ":" (a single colon) mean in "Klass:method(p)"?

Tags: c++, syntax

Today I saw this code:

```
void CameraTree::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    QTreeWidget:dragMoveEvent(event);
}
```

I think the above code is wrong. But:

```
void CameraTree::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
   dragMoveEvent(event);//infinite recursion???
}

void CameraTree::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    QTreeWidget::dragMoveEvent(event);
    // I understand is called dragMoveEvent in class QTreeWidget.
    // But dragMoveEvent is not static??
}
```

And only warned "unused label QTreeWidget", compiled successfully. What does `:` mean?

Comment: As the warning says, it's a **label**.

Comment: you mean?
 QTreeWidget:
dragMoveEvent(event);
.. 
goto QTreeWidget;

Thank you.I never thought about this.

Comment: So the code is wrong. Which is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intended code was probably `QTreeWidget::dragMoveEvent(event);` as you thought. `QTreeWidget::dragMoveEvent(event)` does not need to be static to be invoked from `CameraTree` if `CameraTree` inherits from `QTreeWidget`.
In C++, labels are indicated with a single colon `:`. The reason `QTreeWidget:dragMoveEvent(event);` compiles is because `QTreeWidget:` is interpreted as a label and then `dragMoveEvent(event);` is a recursive call.